# robot framework not running on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I am trying to run robot framework on jenkins locally. When I run the robot framework locally it works perfectly fine but when I try to run it with Jenkin it does not work at all and gives this error. ( using a mac )

```
Started by user Masnad Nehith
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test-robot-framework
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/nihitx/robot-framework-with-jenkins.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/nihitx/robot-framework-with-jenkins.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials githubpass
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/nihitx/robot-framework-with-jenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5a0db902b380bacf39ffc42eb7337f62f4c59b00 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "new push"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5a0db902b380bacf39ffc42eb7337f62f4c59b00
 > git rev-list dda0a775c15f953f2f80a6a4abdf484c333b8000 # timeout=10
[test-robot-framework] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins5706735847575370647.sh
+ robot -d results -v inputEmail:wow5@aurorax.co tests/Aurora.robot
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins5706735847575370647.sh: line 2: robot: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Robot results publisher started...
-Parsing output xml:
Failed!
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test-robot-framework/Results does not exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:460)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:72)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:54)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser.parse(RobotParser.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotPublisher.parse(RobotPublisher.java:217)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotPublisher.perform(RobotPublisher.java:239)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:730)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:621)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
Finished: FAILURE
```

What I understood is that jenkin's cannot find the robot command but I added the robot file to the local bin directory of my computer.

Comment: Looks like a path issue. Why don't you try with absolute path to robot executable? just to conclude that it is only path issue.

Comment: @Waman I fixed the path issue but now i got a permission denied problem. I am using a mac

Comment: then just set the right permission if its a non-root user or run as root.. should fix permission issue is well..

Comment: @Waman how do you do that on a mac?

Comment: You must be able to do it with chmod command. chmod 777 <file> (777 is for full permission, you can set it according to your requirement.

Comment: @Waman my jenkin files are at User/Shared/Jenkins , so should I make the whole Jenkin file 777 or is there a specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Robot Framework installed on Windows or Linux?

If it's on Windows make sure that you wrote in 'Execute batch command' the following: `pybot --outputdir results <Path of you .*robot* test file>`.
And than, you have to add another 'Execute batch command' with an exit command (e.g. for windows it's `EXIT 0`.

Lastly, make sure that on 'Post-build Actions' you the right directory output and files.

Comment: I am using a mac, and I figured out what was wrong, and fixed it, but I got a new issue is that  now i got a permission denied problem.

Comment: Hi Ofer, here is the output, sorry for being so late
https://pastebin.com/mgU7diik

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also got permission denied problem and it can be solved by giving permission to your working directory.
by using  this command
chmod 777 -R path\ofthe\directory

Comment: This might work, but it's very dangerous to use `chmod 777` as everybody can read, write and execute on that path then.

Answer (score 0):

### this issue happens because you doen't set the Robot path to environment variables paths

You can consider to set this path, but we have an easy way to run right now.
Running from python.
Let try this command

python -m robot -d results -v inputEmail:wow5@aurorax.co tests/Aurora.robot

You can see the detailed guide at Part 3.1.1 in Robot Framework Guide (link belows)
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#starting-test-execution
Let try and give me your feedback